# Appending list not working for AWS DynamoDB using Python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to append a value to a DynamoDB table entry:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "history": [
  "638380895-8"
 ],
 "currentbooks": "",
 "email": "ocomford0@craigslist.org",
 "name": "Osborne Comford"
}
```

I'm trying to write the code to add a string entry to 'history' array.

Following is my python code:

```
usersTable = dynamodb.Table("users")
booksTable = dynamodb.Table("books")
bookisbn = event['isbn']
response = usersTable.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': userid,
    },
    UpdateExpression="set history=list_append(history, :s)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={ 
        ':s': bookisbn

    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

It's giving me the error:

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: S"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    response = usersTable.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': userid,
    },
    UpdateExpression="set history=list_append(history,:isbn)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={ 
        ':isbn': [bookisbn]

    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

This is the correct solution...

Answer (score 3):

`list_append` works with 2 lists:

```
list_append(list1, list2)
```

You need to pass the update expression along with the type of the element that you're adding i.e. "L" for a list:

```
response = usersTable.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': userid,
    },
    UpdateExpression="set history=list_append(history, :isbn)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={ 
        ':isbn': {"L": [ { "S" : isbn } ]} # ensure you pass a list

    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.UpdatingListElements) for example.

Comment: Updated. Try again.

Comment: Still giving me the error:   "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: M",

Comment: Forgot about the type for `isbn` itself. Updated.